# Parent Id is not getting populated in Child object - JPA

Tags: jpa

My requirement is while saving parent object with list of child , it should save both parent and its childs.

Issue is it is not setting parent id in child objects, though both parent and childs record getting added in DB. Below is my class details :

**Parent class :**

```
public class View implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    private  String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "view")
    private List<Widget> widgets;
}
```

**Child class :**

```
public class Widget extends implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    private  String id;
    private String title;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "view_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    private View view;
}
```

Comment: The view_id column is null in the database. This view_id column is mapped by the field `view`of the class Widget. So, if the database column is null, it means that the property `view`of the `Widget` objects being saved is null. As simple as that. Make sure it's not null, and instead contains... the view of the widget.

Comment: Here is my payload , I am directly saving this view object with list of widgets and expecting childs to get saved automatically with view id.

```{
  "name": "View 1",
  "widgets": [
    {
      "title": "Widget 1"
    },
    {
      "title": "Widget 2"
    }
  ]

}```

Comment: The JSON payload sent from the browser is irrelevant. What matters is the code that you use to create and populate your JPA entities and save them. Nothing will populate the Widget.view property automagically. You need to do that.